# How to get element by class and id name

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have a javascript code like this:

```js
var confirmbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary-md");
for (var y=0;y<confirmbutton.length; y++) 
  {
  confirmbutton[y].click();
//...
```

Im trying to make a javascript which would press a specific button with the same class and id with the below html.

```HTML
<a href="" id="confirm-btn" class="btn-primary-md">Get it Now</a>
```

but it keeps there is another class with the same class name which keeps getting pressed:

```HTML
<a href="https://example.com" class="btn-primary-md">Upgrade Now</a>
```

How do I get

```HTML
<a href="https://example.com" class="btn-primary-md">Upgrade Now</a>
```

to work with my javascript?

Comment: Since ids are meant to be unique just target the element with that id: [`document.querySelector('#confirm-btn')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Just use [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to provide a more specific selector, or just `document.getElementById("confirm-btn")`.

Comment: What @Andy said.  And really, look at your code.  You're getting element**S** (it's in the function name) and then looping through them all (the for-loop).  Don't just blindly copy code.  Stop and *read* it.  If you don't understand it, do some research.  The MDN is a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: we all expect than you didn't make the mistaking you build a page where yours ID are not unique...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button both by ID and class by using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
let confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#confirm-btn.btn-primary-md");

for (let i = 0; i < confirmButtons.length; i++) {
  console.log("The button text is: " + confirmButtons[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="confirm-btn" class="btn-primary-md">Get it Now</a>
<a href="https://example.com" class="btn-primary-md">Upgrade Now</a>
```

However, as @Andy already suggested in the comments, you better get your button by ID only (assuming your IDs are unique on the page).